# Expected value of non-integer power of complex random variable

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

I have a random variable $X : \Omega\to\mathbb C$. Let $\alpha \in (0,\infty) \backslash \mathbb N$. How is $E(X^\alpha)$ defined and computed?

My confusion is regarding $X^\alpha$ being multivalued. Let $x = X(\omega)$ for some arbitrary $\omega\in\Omega$. I know I can write
$$
x = re^{i\theta} = re^{i\theta + 2\pi i}
$$
so
$$
x^\alpha = r^\alpha e^{i\theta \alpha}
$$
but also
$$
x^\alpha = r^\alpha e^{i\theta \alpha} e^{2\pi i \alpha} \neq r^\alpha e^{i\theta \alpha} 
$$
in general.

So does it even make sense to talk about $E(X^\alpha)$? Do I need to focus on a "principal branch"?

Comment: At first glance, it seems to me that the problem is ill-posed, unless perhaps the range of $X$ is restricted to an appropriately small neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: @Lubin thank you for your comment. What if $|X| = 1$ always, i.e. it always lives on the unit circle? Does that help at all?

Comment: You have to understand that this is way far from my area of expertise. All I know is that unless you can guarantee somehow that you can always choose the same branch of the logarithm (essential ingredient to raising to a nonifnteger power), you are likely to run into trouble.

Comment: @Lubin ok that is still very helpful, thank you